# Remapping an existing project to TFS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs

I accidentally undid my pending changes, however I have the file for the changes. How can I reconnect the backup file to the TFS source control in Visual Studio 2013. Thanks.

Comment: Checkout the files you accidentally undo. Then replace the files with you're changed files and you should have the old situation back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Local Workspace then all you need to do is drop the file over the top of the old one and check in.

If you are using Server Workspaces then you will need to checkout first.

Comment: Does it mean I can just check out latest and then manually replace the project folder?

Comment: It works. I was using Server Workspace and I checked out the project then replaced the whole project with my backup project. Everything is under source control again. I also have to right click and add to source control for those new files that were not in source control.